# modify groovy trait private field

Tags: reflection, groovy, traits

In my unit tests I usually use reflection to manually inject a mock to the tested class' private field:

```
static void setFieldValue(Object instance, String fieldName, Object fieldValue, Class instanceClass) {
        def field = instanceClass.getDeclaredField(fieldName)
        field.accessible = true
        field.set(instance, fieldValue)
    }
```

Where instanceClass is the class/superclass, where the class is actually declared. How can I make it work or achieve same result for a private field being declared on a groovy trait?

Answer (score 1):

My IDE helped me - just use the @ attribute access notation, where the fieldname is package_dots_replaced_with_underscore_TraitName__fieldName, e.g.

```
testee.@pl_kamilroman_DeleteEntityBean__messages
```